# Unable to view SQLite3 database on chrome inspect

Tags: sqlite, ionic2, ionic3

I have created a simple database using `sqlite3` and ran on my device. I am able to query the table through `SELECT` and console the rows out on `chrome inspect`. However, I am unable to view the table created on web sql under the applications tab.

Here are the codes that create the table:

```
this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'particulars.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      this.db = db;
      db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info(rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, age INT)', {})
      .then(res => console.log('Executed SQL'))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
    })
```

Any idea?

Online says that I should extract he db file and then run it on a db compiler. The file that I am extracting is not a db file.

Comment: @g-l please tell if my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should fallback creation of DB from SQLLite to WebSQL:

```
import { Injectable } from '';
import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

const DB_NAME: string = 'particulars.db';
const win: any = window;

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

private _db: any;
constructor(private platform: Platform) {
  if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
   this._db = new SQLite();
   this._db.openDatabase({
     name: DB_NAME,
     location: 'default' // the location field is required
   }).then(() => {
     this._tryInit();
   });
  } else {
    console.warn('Storage: SQLite plugin not installed, falling back to WebSQL. Make sure to install cordova-sqlite-storage in production!');
    this._db = win.openDatabase(DB_NAME, '1.0', 'database', 5 * 1024 * 1024);
    this._tryInit();
  }

  _tryInit() {
    //do query here
  }
}
```

See https://gist.github.com/NickStemerdink/64c782807fc31b7bc9b529ad4b1d56d5.